# How to manually change priority of Intellicode (Intellisense) auto complete suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio, intellicode

I'm writing C# code in Visual Studio 2022.
Whenever I type

```
re
```

on a new line, VISUAL STUDIO suggests

```
ref
```

but I never want "ref", I ALWAYS want

```
return
```

... when I hit TAB. I don't want to type the 3rd letter, I want "return" to be the first/primary suggestion for "re". How can I tell Visual Studio that?

(This is only one example, there are some other suggestions I would also like to change. Note: I'm not trying to add new snippets for new entries, I want to change the priority of the existing ones.)

[image: ref sucks]

Thanks :)

Annotation:

Also really bad are:

- "List.c" -> .Capacity
- "List.co" -> .Concat
- "List.cou" -> .Count

Srsly, who uses those two more often than .Count??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can do this by hand. But you brought this case to our attention, and we are thinking about how to get your preferred behavior.

If you make a VSFeedback ticket with feature request at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion

we can update you when there is progress. Please put intellicode in the title so it lands at the right team.

Comment: Jetbrains code helper is very much better than intellisense. It is a fairly easy thing to fix too I would think.